# error in building ast using byaccj

Tags: java, yacc, parser-generator, jflex

I am using jflex and byaccj to build an AST. 
I am unable to resolve the error and I have used type casting but the error persists

for the following rule in the grammar:

```
program : CLASS Program '{' field_decl '}'      {
                program1 $$ = new program1($1.sval, $2.sval, $4.obj);
        }
        ;
```

and i have declared this in my `.java` file

```
abstract class program extends ASTnode{
}

class program1 extends program {
  private classexp ce = null;
  private String id="Program";
  private ArrayList<field_decl> fdecl = null;
  public program1(classexp ce,String id, ArrayList<field_decl> fdecl) {
    super();
    this.ce = ce;           
    this.id = id;
    this.fdecl = fdecl;
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
{program1 yyval= new program1(val_peek(4).sval,val_peek(3).sval,val_peek(1).obj);}
               ^
required: classexp,String,ArrayList<field_decl>
found: String,String,Object
reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to classexp by method invocation conversion
1 error
```

Comment: Please use the Markdown facilities for formatting code. To see what I did, edit the question and take a look. (Most important: indent code snippets by 4 spaces.) I'm not sure if I got the `^` in the error message in the correct spot, although the error is clear enough without the caret.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `program1` says that the constructor is:

```
public program1(classexp ce,String id, ArrayList<field_decl> fdecl)
```

which takes a `classexp`, a `String` and an `ArrayList<field_decl>` (as indicated in the `required:` line in the error message). You are providing it with:

```
new program1(val_peek(4).sval,val_peek(3).sval,val_peek(1).obj)
```

which is to say, a `String`, another `String`, and an `Object` (as indicated in the `found:` line in the error message). In order to make the provided arguments fit the required parameters, it would be necessary to convert the first `String` to a `classexp`, and this is not possible (as indicated by the `reason:` line in the error message). It will also be necessary to convert the third argument, an `Object` into an `ArrayList<field_decl>`, which is probably also not possible, but one error in a constructor is sufficient to reject the call.